# Уточнение или нет?

Tags: запятая

В субботу, 24 ноября, утром(,) начался форум и...

Уточнение ли это и соответственно нужна ли зпт, ведь если было бы так: В субботу утром начался форум - зпт не нужна

Answer (score 2):

Да, это уточнение - запятая нужная. *"Суббота"* уточняется оборотом *"24 ноября"*, а *"24 ноября"*, в свою очередь, - *"утром"*. Думаю, *"в субботу утром начался..."* можно заменить словосочетанием *"субботним утром"*, поэтому запятую можно опустить.

Answer (score 0):

"УТРОМ" в этом контексте, мягко говоря,  не звучит: фраза официальная, требующая точности, заявленной указанием конкретной даты 24 ноября. Ср.: ***" в субботу 24 ноября в 10 часов..."*** и ***"в субботу утром ..."*** Но Ваш вопрос не об этом.

Лучше всего в предложенном Вами предложении уточняющим обстоятельством сделать только дату   24 ноября. Ср.: ***В субботу, 24 ноября,  утром начался форум.*** Вы просто уточняете, в какую именно субботу месяца утром начался форум, и только это требует уточнения. А утром или днём работал форум - неважно. Ср. ***В субботу утром начался форум.*** Здесь запятые не поставит никто.

Comment: > В субботу утром начался форум. Здесь запятые не поставит никто.  

В деловом тексте  не поставит. А в художественном все возможно.  

> В субботу, утром, начался форум. А уже вечером произошло неожиданное событие ...

Comment: Не нужны и здесь запятые. Интуитивно понимаю почему: когда? в субботу, НО когда? чем? утром. Наречие УТРОМ образовано от существительного в тв.падеже, которое, если вдуматься в значение,  допускает даже, пусть с натяжкой, вопрос КАК? А сочетание "в субботу" только вопрос КОГДА?